# Why does Pillow not recognize the JPEG format?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

Trying out this simple code to write text on an image:

```
import ImageFont
import Image
import ImageDraw

font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 16)
img=Image.new("RGB", (200,200),(120,20,20))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0),"This is a test",(255,255,0),font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

img.save("C:/Users/User/Desktop/test","jpeg")
```

and I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1456, in save  
   save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()] # unknown format
KeyError: 'JPEG'
```

Any idea of how to fix this? I am using Python 2.7.5 Anaconda version in Windows 7 with Eclipse Kepler and PyDev plugin. I also tried `img.save("test.jpeg")` and `img.save("test.png")` resulting in the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out that Eclipse was using PIL rather than Pillow: I just deleted the PIL library reference in Eclipse and made sure Pillow was being used instead and it ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try just running

```
img.save("test.jpg")
```

and see if that does the trick. You shouldn't have to specify the type of file if you also supply a valid extension.

Comment: Sorry bout that, you beat me to my edit with your quick response; I tried that as well.

Comment: hmmm, that's too bad :)

Comment: @Detroitteatime I just got your code to work by saving to a file in the current directory, without putting a file path in - `img.save('test.jpg')`. Have you tried that?